# error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm having trouble with compiling my code for two I2C sensors. I keep getting the error: `expected unqualified-id before '{' token`.

Below is the code I am trying to solve:

```
#include <i2cmaster.h>
#include "Wire.h"    // imports the wire library for talking over I2C 

int led = 13;
//before void setup
#define SENSOR_ADDR_OFF_OFF  (0x4B)
#define SENSOR_ADDR_OFF_ON   (0x4A)
#define SENSOR_ADDR_ON_OFF   (0x49)
#define SENSOR_ADDR_ON_ON    (0x4m8)

// Set the sensor address here
const uint8_t sensorAddr = SENSOR_ADDR_OFF_OFF;
//void setup begins here
void setup()
{
// Start the serial port for output
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  // Join the I2C bus as master
  Wire.begin();

// Set up the ADC on the sensor (reset everything)


i2c_init(); //Initialise the i2c bus
PORTC = (1 << PORTC4) | (1 << PORTC5);//enable pullups

}
//void loop begins here
void loop(){
int dev = 0x5A<<1;
int data_low = 0;
int data_high = 0;
int pec = 0;

i2c_start_wait(dev+I2C_WRITE);
i2c_write(0x07);

// read
i2c_rep_start(dev+I2C_READ);
data_low = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
data_high = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
pec = i2c_readNak();
i2c_stop();

//This converts high and low bytes together and processes temperature, MSB              is   a error bit and is ignored for temps
double tempFactor = 0.02; // 0.02 degrees per LSB (measurement resolution of the MLX90614)
double tempData = 0x0000; // zero out the data
int frac; // data past the decimal point

// This masks off the error bit of the high byte, then moves it left 8 bits and adds the low byte.
tempData = (double)(((data_high & 0x007F) << 8) + data_low);
tempData = (tempData * tempFactor)-0.01;

float celcius = tempData - 273.15;
float fahrenheit = (celcius*1.8) + 32;

Serial.print("Celcius: ");
Serial.println(celcius);

Serial.print("Fahrenheit: ");
Serial.println(fahrenheit);
}
uint8_t left;
uint8_t right;

{
if ((ReadByte(sensorAddr, 0x0, &left) == 0) &&
   (ReadByte(sensorAddr, 0x1, &right) == 0))
{
   // Use a threshold (value from 0-255) to determine if sensor detected a     dark
  // or light surface; the threshold should be modified according to the
  // environment on which the sensor will be used
{    
Serial.print("Left: ");
Serial.println(left);
}{
Serial.print("Right: ");
Serial.println(right);
}}  
delay(1000);
}

// Read a byte on the i2c interface
int ReadByte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data)
{
// Do an i2c write to set the register that we want to read from
Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
Wire.write(reg);
Wire.endTransmission();

//Read a byte from the device
Wire.requestFrom(addr, (uint8_t)1);
if (Wire.available())
{
  *data = Wire.read();
}
else
{
  // Read nothing back
  return -1;
}

return 0;
}

// Write a byte on the i2c interface
void WriteByte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, byte data)
}
{
// Begin the write sequence
Wire.beginTransmission(addr);

// First byte is to set the register pointer
Wire.write(reg);

// Write the data byte
Wire.write(data);

// End the write sequence; bytes are actually transmitted now
Wire.endTransmission();
}
}
```

Comment: Fix your indenting. You'll yourself find the problem. Hint : Check the brackets of `void WriteByte()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have this function, which starts with the wrong brace type.

```
void WriteByte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, byte data)
} // Remove this, it's wrong
{ // Opening brace
    ... the rest of your code ...
} // Closing brace
} // Another closing brace, but I don't know why (I'd just remove it too)
```

You should have.

```
void WriteByte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, byte data)
{ // Opening brace
    ... the rest of your code ...
} // Closing brace
```

Comment: Im still confused on what you mean. Could you please show me this formatted into the code

Comment: So I verified the code again, however, I keep getting an Working_Both_Sensors_With_led.ino:69:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token Apparently it is on line 69. If I remove the brace on line 69 i get another error saying 
Working_Both_Sensors_With_led.ino:70:4: error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'

Comment: @AnoopPatta You have a lot of seemingly unnecessary braces '{' '}'. Clean up all of that and if you're still having problems format your code nicely in your question and clearly indicate what the errors are and where they occur (as in show in your answer where, because a line # alone is not very helpful).